# Install linux wireless driver from windows?

Tags: linux, installation, wifi-driver

I've got a Atheros AR9285 wireless card. I'd like to install the driver so I can access the internet, but I cannot install it without installing the driver to access the internet. See the problem?

Fortunately, I've got a Windows partition set up that can access the internet. Hence this post. How can I go about installing the driver?

Where can I download the driver from? Where should I put it on my hard drive? What command do I use to install the driver?

**Edit:**

I'm on a gateway laptop. I know I can't install the drive from within windows. I'm asking which driver to download and what command installs the driver from within Linux.

**Edit2:**

I can't use LAN in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us the make and model of the laptop and the NIC. 
The best way is to plug into a lan and let your linux OS do its thing from there.

If for whatever reason you can't get a lan connection, you could use a program called [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org) to download the drivers at a public library another computer.

Also, opensuse supports most atheros chips out of the box. As do many distros. Simply switching the linux distro can help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to install a driver for your linux partition from windows partition, but you can download it in windows and put it to a partition that your linux install can access and then install it from linux.

EDIT: Also, why can't you just plug into your router or modem under the linux install? Linux should have a standard LAN driver that should work fine for a wired connection without any additional installation.

Comment: Most modern Linux distribution have decent read support for NTFS, so you may not even need the extra partition, if one isn't easily available. Just mount/copy on the Linux side, then unarchive the driver and install.

Comment: @alexandru, that is an important specification, I didn't mean to imply that adding a partition was the solution, just anything you have available that the distro of Linux can read, whether it is NTFS, a FAT32 thumbdrive, etc.